# Is there a way that i can pull my latest facebook status updates in to my site

Tags: javascript, facebook, feed

just wondering id there was a was of displaying my latest facebook status update on my site?

Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure why you accepted Dennis's answer who posted it later than me.

Comment: @gladoscc it does hurt indeed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using facebook's graph api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/

Answer (score 1):

Use facebook's graph api:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/